# How to fix Issue? id:GradleCompatible

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am setting up firebase with my android application and I am facing an error
implementation `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` Issue `id:GradleCompitable`.

We want to upload picture on firebase with my android application.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}
```

enter code here

This is the error I am facing:

[image: This is the error I am facing]

Comment: Check this link for your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification

Answer (score -1):

Add **'implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'**

> Your issue
>
> Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

To make this gradle dependency same as current version 28, you need to copy the version com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 and change it to com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0

Add this and sync the project. If you again see the issue do the same till the issue resolves.